# NaN error when trying to log json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting a very annoying `NaN` error when trying to log a value from my form and I cannot figure it out.

I tried running `JSON.parse` but it threw me another error `unexpected token o`

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="contact-name">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$('#submit-form').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test = $('form').serializeObject();
    console.log(test);
    console.log(test.contact-name);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are subtracting test.contact and name. You have to use brackets syntax:

```
test["contact-name"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking everywhere for the answer. I just started learning about JSON and I remember before I could do it with dot notation.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy You're welcome. ;-) (Could you also mark my answer as the right one, please?)